# check element has a class starting with string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the last element from a form which has a value like this:

```
var lastOne =$(':text[name^=distanceSlab][value!=""]').last();
```

now I want to find the element which has a class that begins with the string "limit".
I have tried something like:

```
if(lastOne.is("class^='limit'")){
    console.log('BEGINNING WITH LIMIT')
}
```

but it didn't work. How do I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if(lastOne.is("[class^='limit']")){
    console.log('BEGINNING WITH LIMIT');
}
```

You forgot to put `[]` around the selector.

Comment: How to check class name not starts with string "limit"??

Answer (score 1):

```
if(lastOne.attr('class').match(/^limit.+/)) ...
```